# pasar parametros de evnto onclick a funcion javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, mysqli

```
//Obtener los permisos asignados al usuario
$permisosAsignados = $permisos->listarPermisosMarcados($cedula,$id_item);
//mostramos los permisos si estan o no marcados
while ($reg = $permisosAsignados->fetch_object()){
    $html = '<li>
    <a href="#"  data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
    <span>'.$reg->nombre.'</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" >';
    $permisosAsignados1 = $permisos->listarsubMenuPermiso($reg->id_menu);

    while ($reg1 = $permisosAsignados1->fetch_object()){
        $html = $html .'
        <li >
        <a href="#" **onclick="cargarDiv('.$reg1->url.');">'.$reg1->nombre.'</a>**
        </li>';
    }
    $html = $html . '</ul>
    </li>';
    echo $html;
}
```

en esta linea

```
<a href="#" onclick="cargarDiv('.$reg1->url.');">'.$reg1->nombre.'</a>
```

Cargo un dato desde la base de datos `$reg1->url`  para ser enviado a un función JavaScript, pero no funciona, esta variable `$reg1->url` tiene una ruta de un archivo.
pero cuando envio numeros si envia el parametro a la funcion 
espero que me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: gracias por la ayuda con tu codigo   <a href="#" onclick="cargarDiv(\''.$reg1->url.'\');">'.$reg1->nombre.'</a>

Answer (score 0):

prueba escapando las comillas de la siguiente manera: \'

La linea quedaría así:

```
<a href="#" **onclick="cargarDiv(\''.$reg1->url.'\');">'.$reg1->nombre.'</a>
```